# Mongoose Schema.Types.Mixed not working

Tags: mongoose

1. Using mongoose schema.types.Mixed to read existing collections do not recognized the key/value pairs, the console only show "_id" but when trying to access the other key/values I get an undefined

   ```
   var UserSchema1 = new mongoose.Schema({ key: {}});
   var UserSchema2 = new mongoose.Schema({
   userID: Number,
   userName: String,
   password: String});
   var User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema1,'info' );
   router.get('/', function(req, res) {
   User.find({}, function(err, docs) {
   var s = docs;
   console.log(s[0].userName);
   console.log(s[0]._id);
   res.render('userinfo', {users : docs});
   });
   });
   ---- OUTPUT ----
                                   **UserSchema1**         -     **UserSchema2**
    console.log(s[0].userName);       undefined                  mongo
   console.log(s[0]._id);             241245j23j6l26l6       afa88asf8989asfa

   --jade.js--
   ul
       each user in users
     li #{user._id}
     li #{user['userName']}

    Shows only  li with the _id 
    but it creates empty  li  supposedly for user.name
   ```

Answer (score 1):

To use this data type, you can not place `{}`, but `schema.types.Mixed`. So mongoose is an object which is to be saved.

Answer (score 1):

In order to work, you have to use `Schema.Types.Mixed` (uppercased each word) as you can see  [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) (search for `Schema.Types.Mixed`) and without curly braces `{}`.